# How can i sort html element by height and width?

Tags: jquery, css, height, width, jquery-ui-sortable

I would like to sort my `html` elements by height and width so that the element with the highest value of height and width will go to the top. I can already sort elements by height which is featured in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hF9WL/ . But i can't sort the div element with

> "Less width but the same height as medium"

Here is the code:

```js
$('div.sortable').sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(b).height() - $(a).height();
}).appendTo('#container');
```

```css
.small {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}
.medium {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
}
.large {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 300px;
}
.lesser {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="sortable small">Small</div>
  <div class="sortable lesser">Less width but the same height as medium</div>
  <div class="sortable medium">Medium</div>
  <div class="sortable large">Large</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `height` or `width` .. which one have higher priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div.sortable').sort( function(a,b) {
   return $(b).height() - $(a).height() || $(b).width() - $(a).width();;
}).appendTo('#container');
```

Here I have given higher priority to Height and then Width.

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/hF9WL/4/ for full solution I have created